# Scanning a 3d object in ARKit via video camera?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit

This is probably an insanely hard question. So far ARKit works with 3D models which are built in 3d modelling software. I was wondering if there was a way to use iPhone camera to scan 3d object (let's say a car), then use it in ARKit.

Any open source projects available which do this on other platforms or iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for software in the "photogrammetry" category. There are various software tools that will stitch your photos into 3D models, but one option is [Autodesk Remake](http://remake.autodesk.com/about). There is a free version.

Comment: I know this is a very hard question but if I were to code my own way of creating such 3D models from pictures, how should I approach it? Reason being i need to be able to do this on an iOS device. Do you have any pointers or am I asking TOO BIG of a question?

Comment: You should probably not create your own. Look at partnering with the makers of the Trnio app.

Answer (score 1):

ARKit/RealityKit on iPad/iPhone with a LiDAR scanner let you [reconstruct a current scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793918/lidar-and-realitykit-capture-a-real-world-texture-for-a-scanned-model) and obtain a 3D geometry with an Occlusion Material applied. This geometry allows you occlude any object including a human being and physically "interact" with this generated mesh. LiDAR's working distance is up to 5 meters.

However, scanning a car isn't a good idea due to paint's high reflectivity.

Comment: I was trying this out.
In my use-case, I need a more accurate detection and measurement of humans bodies near camera. I was thinking of creating a new configuration for my case, but seemingly got lost. Is there any better way to do it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @AbhishekKumar, The best solution would be to create a question with all the details and cases – what worked and what did not work.