# LiDAR using Unity3D AR Foundation meshing with capture camera texture

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I'm working with AR Foundation Unity Meshing concept. I'm able to load the mesh and export to obj format. But I'm unable to load the mesh with real time capture texture. Can any one suggestions or any reference please.

Comment: Look at this post, please (there's still no solution for realtime capture) – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793918/lidar-and-realitykit-capture-a-real-world-texture-for-a-scanned-model