# RealityKit - Mapping real world textures based on LiDAR scan (not Photogrammetry)

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, lidar, usdz

I want to build an app that lets devices with the LiDAR Scanner scan their environment and share their scans with one another. As of now, I can create the mesh using the LiDAR Scanner and export it as an OBJ file.

However, I would like the ability to map textures and colors onto this model. How would one go on to get the real world texture and place it onto the OBJ model?

**To be clear: I am not referring to Photogrammetry in RealityKit 2.0 since that relies on a macOS device. I would like to achieve what apps like Polycam and Scaniverse are able to achieve**

Thank you!

Comment: There's still no API for LiDAR realtime textures from Cupertino engineers.

Comment: Do you know how apps like Polycam are able to do it? Would love to use something like that or even an SDK which makes this possible.

Comment: I've been trying to find out about it for a long time...

Comment: Ooof that’s rough. Thank you though, please let me know if you figure it out

Comment: My question is still valid. – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793918/lidar-and-realitykit-capture-a-real-world-texture-for-a-scanned-model