# Is it possible to scan real-world object into AR in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit

I wanted to ask if it is possible to scan a real-world object, like a book, and then be able to export a 3d-model from it in swift with RealityKit or ARKit?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a duplicate question, check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793918/lidar-and-realitykit-capture-a-real-world-texture-for-a-scanned-model

Comment: look into [object capture](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/object-capture/)